# Make iFrame displayed via 3rd party 100% of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to make an `iFrame` that is delivered via a third party 100% height of it's parent.

https://jsfiddle.net/ehfs63qt/1/

I don't know how best to do this. Currently I've been trying CSS like the below only It's not the most efficient and I need a use case of each media query...

```
.flx-embed > div iframe {
  display: block !important;
  width: 150% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  transform: translateX(-20%);
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: A quick suggestion would be if you are using jQuery to load the iframe dynamically, just after you `.append($iFrame)` you can change the style of the parent element with `$(iFrame).parent.css("width", "100%")` that should do the trick. Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you elaborate please @N.Ivanov?

Comment: I got the understanding that you are loading the iframe dynamically and the dynamic loading is causing your styles not to apply the `width: 100%`, so what I suggested was to update the css on the parent element dynamically as well. After going over the jsFiddle that you provided I saw that you are facing another problem where the `iframe` does not want to become 100% width. If that is indeed your problem I am sorry for the above suggestion and I will check out the jsFiddle provided and if I find a fix will come back with it! Hope this helps!